# How can i merge several functions that do the same thing on different scope objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my question is that i have a form that allows for the user to add new inputs, i do this in the controller via a simple `push` to an array of objects.

```
$scope.urls = [{}];

$scope.addUrl = function() {
    $scope.urls.push({});
};
```

Just like that, the thing is i do this for 4 other scope objects as well, the function is exactly the same but due to the different scope objects i find myself having to define this same function 4 different times in my controller in order to get it to work...

Is there any way i can put all of these into the same object?

`data-ng-model="url.text"`

That is how my ng-model looks like at the moment, i don't really the URL's to be saved into a "text" key but i couldn't get it to work any other way.

So i basically just need to be able to pass `urls` *(or whatever the name of the scope array that contains the urls will be)* into a function that will push an empty object into the given array, so i can avoid redundancy and just have one function.

Comment: Put the function in a service, which all your controllers can use.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking. Comment if you meant something else.

Controller:

```
$scope.addUrl = addNewElement;

initializeUrlGroups();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function initializeUrlGroups () {
    ['urls1', 'urls2', 'urls3', 'urls4'].forEach(function (referenceName) {
       $scope[referenceName] = [{}];
    });
}

function addNewElement (referenceName) {
    $scope[referenceName].push({});
};
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="addUrl('urls1')">Add URL (Group 1)</button>
<button ng-click="addUrl('urls2')">Add URL (Group 2)</button>
<button ng-click="addUrl('urls3')">Add URL (Group 3)</button>
<button ng-click="addUrl('urls4')">Add URL (Group 4)</button>
```

Or...

HTML:

```
<button ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4]" ng-click="addUrl('urls' + n)">
    Add URL (Group {{n}})</button>
```